# Display custom error instead of WiX default error for "MainEngineThread is returning 1624"

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3, wix3.7

After silent installation of WiX MSI, it writes the default MSI error when the Instance or Transform is invalid. It's not even reaching to custom action method before that MSI fails.

`MSI (s) (A0:D0) [00:48:39:793]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0 MSI (s) (A0:D0) [00:48:39:793]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0 MSI (s) (A0:D0) [00:48:39:793]: Note: 1: 2203 2: Instance26 3: -2147287038  MSI (s) (A0:D0) [00:48:39:793]: **MainEngineThread is returning 1624**`

How to throw a custom message instead of a default MSI error saying instance or transform is invalid?

Comment: [Maybe have a look at this cmd file](https://github.com/fpschultze/CmdXenAppMaintenance/blob/254449cec8a0f4696d48e785b81cdd06d229f414/Library/InstallMsi.cmd#L143). Do you want to check for a few of these error conditions specifically?

Comment: That's right. I want to add condition on some of these places but it's failing.      <Custom Action="SetMsiNewInstance" Before="AppSearch"><![CDATA[ACTION = "INSTALL" AND MYINSTANCE = "DontUseThis" AND SECONDEXECUTE <> 1]]></Custom>
      <Custom Action="SetTransforms" Before="AppSearch"><![CDATA[ACTION = "INSTALL" AND MYINSTANCE = "DontUseThis" AND SECONDEXECUTE <> 1]]></Custom>